# C++ DLL works from 32 bit Excel VBA, but not when recompiled for 64 bit Excel

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2010, dll, 32bit-64bit

Using Visual Studio 2010 Premium I have built a c++ DLL in both 32 and 64 bit flavors for calling from Excel 2010 visual basic.  It works great with 32 bit Excel, but with 64 bit Excel I get the dreaded "Error 53, file not found".  The DLL contains just two exported functions, one function runs ok with Excel-64 but the other function triggers the error.  Dependency Walker did not help me.  The problem ought to be a missing dependency, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  It was a boneheaded mistake with management of folder paths.  I was well aware that that this sort thing causes an Error 53, but I thought that wasn't my problem, but it was.

For Excel VBA to be able to load the DLL, either CurDir() has to be set to the folder containing the DLL before calling a function in it, or the entire path needs to be in the VBA Declare statement.  I thought I was changing the CurDir before the call, but I wasn't.